# Change Codeigniter Directory Structure

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, directory-structure

default CodeIgniter is had different folder for views, controller, and models but it become hard when the project is big, It will be easy if I can keep views, controller and model files in the same folder

```
controller
   c1
   c2
model
  m1
  m2
Views
  v1
  v2
```

Now i need

```
module1
  c1
  v1
  m1

module 2
  c2
  v2
  m2
```

Comment: Look up codeigniter hmvc.

Comment: thanks @BrianGottier got the point this is what I was looking - exact word to search HMVC

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for actual HMVC you can find it here :
[Modular Extensions - HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc)

HMVC will do two things for you
- Module separation (the structure you asked for it) 
- calling and running module's controllers/models/views from each other

Answer (score 0):

Use HMVC Pattern and its easy to use.
http://developers.ph/codeigniter/hmvc-pattern-codeigniter-php-framework/